# What is the fixed format of CDA document

Tags: hl7, cda

I am working on importing and exporting CDA health records. From my research i’v found that every CDA has a different format.
I cant find anything specific related to the format of CDA document so that i can create CDA document from the data that is available in my database. I need help in understanding the nodes available in CDA document.

Answer (score 1):

The question you posed is a bit vague because there are alot of variations of cda documents but they do all follow the cda schema

Here is the MDHT java api for CDA https://github.com/mdht/mdht-models/releases/tag/v3.0.1.20170825_Consol2

here is a site with CDA examples

http://hl7-c-cda-examples.herokuapp.com

Comment: Just to confirm that all CDA must validate the defined HL7 CDA schema. At this URL you can fine more information about the standard, download it, and also obtain the XML schema: https://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/product_brief.cfm?product_id=7